# Microsoft Graph InTune Beta API's - Unable to add app to app policy

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, intune

I am attempting to use Intune specific beta Graph APIs to assign apps to an iOS managed app protection policy. I am able to create the app policies using the endpoint documented below:

https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/api/intune_mam_iosmanagedappprotection_create

When created via API, the app "deployedCount" is 0 until specific apps are added in the admin console UI.

Now, I am attempting to retrieve apps added to any policy by API using the endpoint documented below.

https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/api/intune_mam_mobileappidentifierdeployment_list

I get a 400 bad request response that appears to say this endpoint either does not exist or is not responding correctly. This seems unlike if I mistyped an endpoint.

Response I receive:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "No method match route template",
    "message": "No OData route exists that match template ~/entityset/key/navigation with http verb GET for request   /MAMAdmin/MAMAdminFEService/managedAppPolicies('T_338de6df-386d-4f1b-a51c-a0d189c61722')/mobileAppIdentifierDeployments.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "79514f29-4dca-48a5-a2de-5d14138577d7",
      "date": "2017-02-08T17:46:52"
    }
  }
}
```

Response if I mistyped:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'asdfasdf'.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "e86d84ab-f062-4780-af3c-9afae6e7bc82",
      "date": "2017-02-08T18:53:29"
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello this is Alemeshet Alemu from MSFT.

Sorry, the API documentation is a bit out sync. Could you try with $expand?

GET /managedAppPolicies/{managedAppPoliciesId}?$expand=mobileAppIdentifierDeployments

- Alemeshet Alemu (MSFT)

Comment: Thanks Alemeshet! This worked. To follow up, does this also apply for the PATCH to update the apps applied to a given policy? https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/api/intune_mam_managedapppolicydeploymentsummary_update

Comment: No Problem, thank you for reporting cb.dev. The beta documentation needs to be scubbed to match implementation. To update app to which policy is deployed use:POST ~/managedAppPolicies/{managedAppPoliciesId}/updateMobileAppIdentifierDeployments
{
    "mobileAppIdentifierDeployments": 
    [
    { "mobileAppIdentifier": { "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.androidMobileAppIdentifier", "packageId": "com.microsoft.office.outlook" } }, 
    { "mobileAppIdentifier": { "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.androidMobileAppIdentifier", "packageId": "com.microsoft.office.word " } }
    ]
}

Comment: @AlemeshetAlemu-MSFT While trying to update the policy, I see the following in the response:

`{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'updateMobileAppIâ€Œâ€‹dentifierDeployments'.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "2cb2370b-48ea-4aab-a522-679280a4dcf9",
            "date": "2017-08-16T07:38:09"
        }
    }
}`

Can you please help me out here. The API in the documentation does not work

Comment: API signature has been updated. Answered a similar question here - https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/886#issuecomment-358191556